# Disabling and enabling google play protect scanning via intent (or any remote method)

Tags: android, android-intent, mdm, device-management, google-play-protect

I'm attempting to install some internally developed applications via MDM to a group of Android devices, but because we won't be utilizing the play store for those applications, I get constant "Blocked by Play Protect" and the users have to select "Install Anyway" which is leading to issues as people are not selecting this option.

I've noticed that my MDM supports sending Android "Intents" and I was wondering if there was any possible way to utilize this to disable the play protect scanning option so that I can install the applications/updates and then re-enable the play scanning services at a later date?

Or honestly any other remote method suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible . submit your application to google so you don't receive block message
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals

Comment: I appreciate your response, unfortunately this isn't an option for our institution. This is such a frustrating design by google, if its an option that you can change manually then you should be able to manage it remotely with you MDM as well.